# Filtering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Good day,

I am having a little problem. I want to filter my products by size, but the products can't be filtered somehow. When I `console.log` the products, this appears:

```
[]
[]

filter.js:24 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
filter.js:24 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

The products array is being logged 4 times, twice empty and then twice with the products in them.
I have checked if I have `console.logged` the array before, but I don't see anything. I am looking forward to your responses.

My code of the filter:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { listProduct } from '../../actions/productActions';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Filter = () => {
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);

  const { products, loading, error } = productList;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProduct());
  }, []);
  console.log(products);

  return (
    <div className="filter">
      <label>
        Order:
        <select>
          <option value="lowest">Lowest to Highest</option>
          <option value="highest">Highest to Lowest</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        Size:
        <select
          className="size"
          onChange={(e) => {
            if (e.target.value === 'S') {
              return products.filter((product) => product.size === 'S');
            } else if (e.target.value === 'XS') {
              alert('Extra small');
            } else if (e.target.value === 'M') {
              alert('MEDIUM');
            } else if (e.target.value === 'L') {
              alert('LARGE');
            } else if (e.target.value === 'XL') {
              alert('EXTRA LARGE');
            } else {
              alert('ALL');
            }
          }}
        >
          <option value="">ALL</option>
          <option value="XS">XS</option>
          <option value="S">S</option>
          <option value="M">M</option>
          <option value="L">L</option>
          <option value="XL">XL</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

Comment: It is being consolelogged once per rederization at least.

Comment: @Elanochecer how can i fix this?

Comment: The two empty arrays appear because in the first render, the array is not loaded and thus empty. So the filter in the `onChange `handler does not work? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @Gh05d but the filter doesnt work

Comment: Well, do the elements of the array have a size property?

Comment: @Gh05d the elements in the array are product objects and the objects have got the size prop

Answer (score 0):

Your filter does not work the way you intend it to, because it does not mutate the original array. From the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

I guess you would have to move the filter functionality to where you render the `productList`.